# Timeout when uploading files to webspace by FTP (e. g. using Filezilla)

Tags: ftp

Since some days I encounter problems when uploading files to my webspace by FTP, e. g. using Filezilla: The progressbar proceeds to 100% very quickly (less than 1 s), then everything hangs and after some time Filezilla reports a timeount:

```
Status: Resolving address of ulrichbangert.de
Status: Connecting to 85.13.140.237:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Starting upload of D:\Gemeinsame Dateien\Internet\Homepage\heimat\Goslar_Kirchen\2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/heimat/Goslar_Kirchen"...
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (85,13,140,237,196,109).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (85,13,140,237,197,15).
Command:    STOR 2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ulrichbangert.de
Status: Connecting to 85.13.140.237:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Starting upload of D:\Gemeinsame Dateien\Internet\Homepage\heimat\Goslar_Kirchen\2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/heimat/Goslar_Kirchen"...
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (85,13,140,237,196,71).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (85,13,140,237,196,214).
Command:    STOR 2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  File transfer fa
```

I've configured passive FTP
My provider says he cannout find any errors in the logfiles. Kabel Deutschland, Cable TV featuring internet access, Modem connected directly to PC.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (85,13,140,237,196,109).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD
Response:   226 Transfer complete
```

The data transfer by itself works because otherwise it would not possible to get the directory listing like done here. This means it is not a problem of active vs. passive mode nor it is a general connectivity problem.

```
Command:    STOR 2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 2016-10-26_Neuwerkkirche_Panorama.json
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
```

Since data transfer for directory listing reliably works but data transfer for file upload always fails I would suggest that this is either a server problem (unlikely, other customers would complain too) or something is tampering with the connection. This might for example be a firewall but it might also be a FTP helper probably employed by Kabel Deutschland because they don't use public IPv4 addresses for most customers (i.e. DS-Lite). This FTP helper cannot work properly with FTPS connections (i.e. FTP over SSL like in your case) but in theory should not do any harm in passive mode, but maybe it does.

To narrow down the cause of the problem I would suggest that you try the transfer from a different computer in the same network. If this fails too try the transfer from another network (internet cafe, mobile network...) using the same system which failed initially. If all of this fails it looks like a problem at the server end, i.e. contact the provider where the FTP server is hosted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will install an FTP client on my smartphone as  I have no other computer. Then I can test via WLAN and via mobile internet.

Comment: Update: In the meantime I installed an FTP client on my Smartphone and uploaded some files via WLAN and Kabel Deutschlands modem. Worked without problems. Thus there seems to be a problem on my desktop computer. Problem management of Window7 cannot locate a problem. What can I do now?

Comment: @Sempervivum: I don't know much about Windows 7 but as far as I know there is a firewall too which can cause trouble. This you might try to switch it off. Maybe you also have some antivirus or similar installed which intercepts the traffic.

Comment: This was one of the first actions I tried (my webspace provider all-inkl recommend it) and it didn't help. Gave it one more try right now - the result is the same, no improvement.